# How to obtain the distributions of linear model parameters?

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear, posterior

For a linear model
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + …… + \sigma^2$$
Assuming $\beta_0, \beta_1,……$ are random varibles,
how to obtain the distributions of these parameters?

It seems that Bayesian regression obtains the posterior distributions of $\beta_0, \beta_1,……$, but the posterior distributions are not the real distributions of $\beta_0, \beta_1,……$, because the variances of the posterior distributions will all converge to zeros when there are enough samples.

Comment: as the number of data points goes to infinity.. why shouldn't the posterior variance go to 0?

Comment: What *are* the real distributions of the parameters? This is a serious question. What do you assume them to be?

Comment: I don't see why the variances will converge to zero.  If indeed the $\beta_i$ are random *and each observation is independent of the others,* then this shouldn't happen.  If instead you consider obtaining ever larger numbers of observations *conditional on a single value of $(\beta_0,\ldots, \beta_k),$* then we would expect the posterior to converge *to that fixed value.*  The key to understanding (and answering) your question therefore must include some description of exactly what you allow to change and what you keep fixed during "convergence."

Comment: Why are you adding $\sigma^2$ (presumably the variance of a noise term) instead of the noise term itself in your model? Note that $\sigma^2$ must be positive, for starters, whereas an additive error term would usually be defined to have 0 mean.

Comment: @Tim， for example， generate a sample set $\{y|X\}$ based on $\beta$s generated from different given distributions, such as $\beta_0: N(\mu_0,\sigma_0)$, $\beta_1: N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$..., how to estimate $\mu_0,\sigma_0,\mu_1,\sigma_1$ from  $\{y|X\}$.

Comment: @shimao Because $\beta$ can be random but unobservable variables in applications while x and y are observable variables.

Comment: @Tim，I don't really know what the distribution is. For example, I have a vehicle model has a parameter $\beta$ which is a function of vehicle weight, but since the passengers randomly changes,  $\beta$ has randomness. When the weight has not been measured in my data, I hope to estimate the distrbution of $\beta$ or vehicle weight.

Comment: @whuber, I think my question is $\beta$ has randomness but unobserverable, x and y are observations. The randomness of $\beta$ decreases with the number of observation increasing, but the physical background of the randomness of $\beta$ does not related to the observations. I think the assumption of Bayesian regression is that $\beta$ is fixed coefficients, but my application these coefficients may change (not large, for example, vehicle mass).

Comment: @Glen_b，you're right, my expression is not right. I'm just trying to show that Bayesian regression still converges the uncertainties to a normal distribution with a mean of 0. Why the uncertainties can not be present in the $\beta$ (Uncertainties changes with $x$).

Comment: Your description seems to be of *estimates* of *fixed* parameters rather than of randomly varying parameters.  If indeed those parameters are random, *how* are they random?  What is actually going on?  For instance, would different values of the $\beta_i$ apply to different observations or not?

Comment: @whuber My read of the comment to Tim is that the effect the independent variable has on the dependent variable changes depending on the value of the independent variable. In that case, I can see why one might call that a distribution, though I’d say that “nonlinear effect” is more accurate.

Comment: @whuber the randomness of $\beta$ is independent with $x$. For example, $\beta$ related to vehicle mass, and $x$ related to vehicle speeds, $y$ is the energy consumption of the vehicle which is the combined effect of vehicle mass and speeds. For each trip, speeds are the explanatory variable, which is the primary impact factor, but the vehicle mass also varies due to that the number of passagers may change. If I only have measured data of speeds and energy consumption, generally the vehicle mass is assumed to be constant, I hope to build a more comprehensive probabilistic model.

Comment: @Dave the randomness of $\beta$ is independent of $x$. In some scenarios, there may be independent random variations in the parameters of the linear model, or in other words, the randomness of the response variable is not fixed but   scaled by the explanatory variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. The answer is that in the usual conceptual approach, the regression coefficients are not assumed to be random variables, but *fixed*. So you can think of an underlying process on the population level with constant parameters, and it is only your *estimates* of $\beta$ based on finite samples that have distributions due to, for example, sampling variability. Note that the underlying process $f(Y|X=x)$ described by the linear model is nevertheless **not** deterministic. This is due to the error term.

On the population level, you can think of the process for example as a machine that takes an input and has a fixed protocol to produce an output, but still produces outputs with some variability. This is not because the inputs or the protocol are stochastic, but a single *realization* of the protocol is stochastic.

So, for $n \rightarrow \infty$, you will have $\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}) \rightarrow 0$, $\text{Var}(\hat{Y}|X=x) \rightarrow 0$ ($\hat{Y}$ being the predicted conditional mean) and also $\text{Var}(\hat{\sigma}^2) \rightarrow 0$, but the width of your prediction intervals will still always be $>0$ (assuming $\sigma^2>0$).

Edit: My answer is more from a frequentist perspective dealing with sampling distributions. In a Bayesian approach, you indeed obtain probability distributions ober $\beta$. It is crucial to interpret this as your subjective belief about the location of $\beta$, however, not the true distribution of $\beta$ itself. Of course, having more data will make your beliefs converge stronger to a certain value.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I mean that generally, Bayesian regression assumes coefficients are fixed, but they can be random variables. if assuming they are random variables, how to obtain their distributions?